# Drools how to get the last element in the list

Tags: java, drools

Here is my rule:

```
rule "rahultest" 
salience 200
no-loop true
when
    $parentObject : parentObject()
    $child : ChildObject() from $parentObject.childs //here I want to put the code like 
then


end
```

I want to run this rule only for the last element how I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming childs it's a list and not null and not empty:

```
rule "rahultest" 
when
    $parentObject : parentObject()
    $child : ChildObject()
        from $parentObject.getChilds().get( $parentObject.getChilds().getSize() - 1 )
then
 ...
end
```

You might add a getter getLastChild() to parentObject, would simplify this somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

```
rule "Last Activity"

    when
        $inst:Instance(  )
        $ev:Event( activity=="Verify Exit" )
          from $inst.getEvents().get($inst.getEvents().size() - 1 )
    then 
        SendMessage.ReportMessage(kcontext,$inst);      
    end
```